# Use less temporary space in DWithin join

Tags: postgis

I only have 12GB of free space. Is there a way to create this table without creating a bunch of temporary files? It runs out of space and never completes. I want to know how many cities are within 80km of each city.

```
SELECT a.k, count(a) x 
FROM     cities AS a 
JOIN     cities AS b   
  ON     ST_DWithin(a.geog, b.geog, 80000)   
 AND     a.k != b.k 
WHERE    a.l = true 
group by a.k 
;
```

QUERY PLAN

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
 Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=1282860.42..1285716.94 rows=24280 width=15)
   Group Key: a.k
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1282860.42..1285372.97 rows=20234 width=15)
         Workers Planned: 2
         ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=1281860.39..1282037.44 rows=10117 width=15)
               Group Key: a.k
               ->  Sort  (cost=1281860.39..1281885.69 rows=10117 width=348)
                     Sort Key: a.k
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..1281187.39 rows=10117 width=348)
                           ->  Parallel Seq Scan on cities a  (cost=0.00..11417.42 rows=111968 width=380)
                                 Filter: l
                           ->  Index Scan using citiesn_geog_idx on cities b  (cost=0.41..11.33 rows=1 width=39)
                                 Index Cond: (geog && _st_expand(a.geog, '80000'::double precision))
                                 Filter: ((a.k <> k) AND (a.geog && _st_expand(geog, '80000'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(a.geog, geog, '80000'::double precision, true)
)
(14 rows)
```

when I only limit it to 1000 it is really fast

```
Limit  (cost=0.83..127479.34 rows=1000 width=15) (actual time=0.858..440.869 rows=1000 loops=1)
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.83..3095179.08 rows=24280 width=15) (actual time=0.856..440.550 rows=1000 loops=1)
         Group Key: a.k
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.83..3094814.88 rows=24280 width=348) (actual time=0.711..423.748 rows=42526 loops=1)
               ->  Index Scan using citiesk on cities a  (cost=0.42..47380.58 rows=268722 width=380) (actual time=0.027..4.349 rows=1043 loops=1)
                     Filter: l
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 79
               ->  Index Scan using citiesn_geog_idx on cities b  (cost=0.41..11.33 rows=1 width=39) (actual time=0.083..0.389 rows=41 loops=1043)
                     Index Cond: (geog && _st_expand(a.geog, '80000'::double precision))
                     Filter: ((a.k <> k) AND (a.geog && _st_expand(geog, '80000'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(a.geog, geog, '80000'::double precision, true))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 11
 Planning Time: 0.480 ms
 Execution Time: 448.505 ms
(13 rows)
```

after vacuum analyze and with count(a.k)

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=3058755.01..3059179.53 rows=24258 width=15)
   Group Key: a.k
   ->  Sort  (cost=3058755.01..3058815.66 rows=24258 width=7)
         Sort Key: a.k
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..3056988.28 rows=24258 width=7)
               ->  Seq Scan on cities a  (cost=0.00..12999.33 rows=268413 width=39)
                     Filter: l
               ->  Index Scan using citiesn_geog_idx on cities b  (cost=0.41..11.33 rows=1 width=39)
                     Index Cond: (geog && _st_expand(a.geog, '80000'::double precision))
                     Filter: ((a.k <> k) AND (a.geog && _st_expand(geog, '80000'::double precision)) AND
 _st_dwithin(a.geog, geog, '80000'::double precision, true))
(10 rows)
```

Comment: run `VACUUM ANALYZE cities` to guarantee the planer can work with updated table statistics; with more index use, less size for fetched rows is needed. count only the id column, not the full row (`COUNT(b.k)`); this reduces the size of the returned rows (estimated as `width` in bytes per row), for each node in the plan. you might also want to check if you can create *an actual table* with that query, since much memory overhead can be saved if no output has to be generated...but I'm not 100% sure of the impact here

Comment: it was able to do it. I think using count(a.k) helped a lot! I'm still interested, however, if there is any other optimizations that I could do on a query just like this because I have similar ones that I want to write so I'll leave this question open for other replies

Comment: If you  have lots of entries with `a.l = false`, you could try making the index `citiesk` a partial one on `k` ( `create index citiesk on cities (k) where l;`)

Comment: You can replace a.k != b.k with a.k > b.k which reduces the comparisons from n*(n-1) to n*(n-1)/2, ie, it halves them.

Comment: Also, as I believe temporary results will have to be written to memory/disk, before group by is called, this ought to reduce your space problems also.